# How can I Setup data to debug android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I'm testing my app to react on certain scenarios, that may ocurr when some properties (stored on shared preferences) are missing or have different values. To achieve that, I want to run some lines of java code that can alter that shared preferences without running the entire app. Is that possible?

I tried using TestUnit Classes but the run only on the host computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you injected the shared preferences, you can unit test your code by mocking the injected class (with [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) for example). 
More on this topic in the [official site](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html).

You can also unit test your shared preferences dependant code with the help of [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/). The main idea would be to access your shared preference as you would do in your code, but with the context provided by robolectric. This way you can just store something on the real shared preferences before the test, and then test the code.

I Hope it helped, happy coding!